# Kubernetes - Shared environment variables for all Pods

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

We have to set https_proxy & http_proxy for internet access from our cluster instances.

https_proxy & http_proxy environment variables should be exported to all pods so that application can access external sites.

We are using helm charts so is there common place we can set these environment variables so all pods can access internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using PodPreset object to pass common environment variables and other params to all the matching pods.

## Add label `setproxy:true` to all pods

The below `PodPreset` object would inject `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable to all pods that match label `setproxy:true`

```
apiVersion: settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: PodPreset
metadata:
  name: inject-proxy-var
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      setproxy: true
  env:
    - name: HTTPS_PROXY
      value: "https_proxy"
    - name: HTTP_PROXY
      value: "http_proxy"
```

Follow the link for more help --> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/

## You should enable Pod Preset in your cluster. follow the below link

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/

Comment: @P Ekambaram Error: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "PodPreset" in version "settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1". My kubernetes version 1.13.0

Comment: you need to enable PodPreset in your cluster. see the updated instructions

Comment: `PodPreset` has been removed from newer release of k8s :(

Comment: What is the way to achieve this now if PodPreset has been removed now

Comment: take a look at PodPreset Based Webhook Admission Controller project --> https://github.com/redhat-cop/podpreset-webhook

Comment: Should be `setproxy: "true"` (true as a string), otherwise there are errors when creating the PodPreset and also when setting the label in a pod.

Answer (score -5):

If i understood it correctly, you want to set env variable to container. If this is correct understanding, You can use below configuration for container to set env variables

```
env:
- name: HTTPS_PROXY
  value: "Value"
- name: HTTP_PROXY
  value: "Value"
```

You can check more details at :https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#define-an-environment-variable-for-a-container

Comment: Im looking to set env variable to all containers in common place

Comment: Ok..  As you using helm... Declare variables in values. Yaml and use those for every container. But that template logic  you need to write for individuals container configuration.

Comment: Yes I have implemented that way but is there a way to do common for all containers in 1 place?

Comment: No. As per my knowledge this is not possible.