# Kubernetes: Set environment variable in all pods

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to provide environment variables which will be set in all pods instead of configuring in each pods spec?

If not natively possible in Kubernetes, what would be an efficient method to accomplish it? We have Helm, but that still requires a lot of duplication.

This old answer suggested "PodPreset" which is no longer part of Kubernetes: [Kubernetes - Shared environment variables for all Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54550933/591975)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using a [mutating admission webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) to inject the environment variable into the pod manifest.

There are more details on implementing webhooks [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#request).

Comment: Hello @[sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/591975/sean). Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do that for EVERY single pod in the cluster (if that is what you meant), but you CAN do it for every single pod within an application or service.

For example, via a Deployment, you can set a variable within the pod template, and all replicas will carry that value.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ...
        env:
        - name: VAR_NAME      # <---
          value: "var_value"  # <---
        ...
```

In this (edited) example, all 5 replicas of the nginx will have the environment variable `VAR_NAME` set to the value `var_value`.

You could also use a configmap (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) or secrets (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables) to set environments variables from a shared location, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. This is what we are doing. But are looking to do for all deployments as we have a few common configs that most deployments use.

Comment: Then my suggestion is a base chart (or deployment) that has those values as either a configmap or secret, and then you can use that in all other charts, and maintain the base values using either helm or your choice of CI/CD. One important caveat though, and that is if you accidentally delete the deployment or helm release, all the pods depending on that mount will fail to start as they're trying to mount something that no longer exists.

Comment: Hello @[sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/591975/sean). Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solves your issue.