# how to set/update enviroment variable for running pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way to update the `env` variables for all the running pods in the deployment ?
I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881102/kubernetes-set-environment-variable-in-all-pods), but still cant find a solution. I tried setting some env varibales for a deployment like `kubectl set env deployment/<deployment-name> -n <namespace> foo=bar`, but executing the `printenv | grep foo` gives nothing inside the container. there is the a mention of doing the same using [configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/), but I am unable to find an example where I can create a key value for a config map and access that form inside the pod?

Comment: It sounds like you might already have a [mcve], with a specific YAML manifest and a specific command with an unexpected output.  Can you [edit] the question to include these details?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to update environment variables on a Pod. That part is immutable, once the pod was created.

You should consider using ReplicaSets, Deployments, or StatefulSets, rather than creating Pods directly. Upper-level objects are meant to control Pods lifecycle, might simplify things for you.

As also suggested by MZM, you might use ConfigMaps, although I'm not certain new keys would actually show in your environment starting a new process (in older k8s version, any change to secret to configmaps/secrets required pods to be restarted), and even if new processes environment would reflect such changes nowadays, assuming recent k8s runtime: it's pretty certain that any running process would not adopt those, you would still need to restart them.